# How do I center the navigation menu?

Tags: html, css, alignment

I am using the following codes to create a layout, the issue is, the navigation menu won't center, the text centers, but the rest of the navigation bar doesn't.

Here is my HTML:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
</head>

<body>
    <div id="container">
    <h1>Test</h1>


    <ul id="navigation">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Projects</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>


    <div id="content">
    </div>

    <div id="footer">
        <p>Test</p>
    </div>

    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

And here is my CSS:

```
/***** Body *****/
body {
    font-family: arial, helvetica;
    text-align:center;
}

div#container {
}

/***** Navigation Menu *****/

ul#navigation {
    margin: 20px;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    width: 525px;
}

ul#navigation li {
    display: inline;
}

ul#navigation a {
    text-decoration:none;
    padding: 5px 0;
    width: 100px;
    background: #485e49;
    color: #eee;
    float: left;
    text-align:center;
}

ul#navigation a:hover {
    background: #FF00FF;
    text-align:left;
}

ul#navigation a:active {
    text-align:right;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your `ul#navigation` to

```
ul#navigation {
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    width:400px;
    margin:0 auto;    
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/jasongennaro/3WS7B/

What happened is your `width` was off.  Once that was fixed to `400px`, applying `margin:0 auto` worked.

Comment: Wait, why was the width an issue?

Comment: You had more `width` applied than necessary.  The `nav` was only `400px` but you had it at `525px`.  Here is the difference and why it wasn't lining up: http://jsfiddle.net/jasongennaro/3WS7B/1/

Comment: Oh...yes, I see now. And no, you weren't accusatory at all. Maybe I came off as defensive, heh. Thanks for explaining. :)

Comment: Always hard to tell tone etc. online, @Purmou! Glad we both figured it out ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You can add this to the `ul#navigation` css to center it:

```
margin:0 auto 0 auto;
```

Alternatively:

```
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
```

Comment: Oh... for some reason it wasn't appearing for me in my browser. Upon switching to firefox it appears to work.

Comment: @Jacob: The width doesn't have anything to do with it (Jason said that in reference to the smallness of the jsfiddle screen). If you expand the "Result" box it will show it centered perfectly.

Comment: @Jacob.  The problem had to do with the `Width`.  See my answer.

Comment: @Jacob: What browser were you using?

Comment: @Purmou, if `width` doesn't have anything to do with it, than why does your fiddle have `width:400px` in the `ul#navigation`, when the original shows `525px`... something I pointed out but you didnt mention in your answer?

Comment: @Jason: It wasn't a problem, though...I only changed it so that it would display centered in the jsfiddle result box without overflowing.

Comment: Fair enough @Purmou... Apologies for the accusatory tone.  However, `width` was the problem.  As you can see in this fiddle ( http://jsfiddle.net/jasongennaro/3WS7B/1/ ), the original extra space was throwing it off.  Changing your fiddle to fit the window happened to stumble on the answer.